# Deploying ASP.NET Core MVC web application on AWS causes SQL Server exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, deployment, asp.net-core-mvc

I get this exception when I deploy/publish my web app using beanstalk AWS

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> Win32Exception: No such host is known.
>
> Unknown location
>
> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling, string accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)

Appsettings:

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "GameDbConnection": "Data Source = MYPCNAME,1434\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = Mydatabasename;Integrated Security = True;User Id = username;Password = mypassword; Connect Timeout = 30;Encrypt = False;TrustServerCertificate = False;ApplicationIntent = ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover = False"
```

I have tried everything, I allowed all ports through firewall, enabled everything, typed my connection string to `web.config` which I have found in debug publish. This file didn't have a connection string value in it so I had to type it down and then deploy.

Please help me.

Comment: If you have tried everything, then there is nothing left for us to suggest. Seriously though, how can you expect us to know what is going wrong? We don't have access to your system. You have to to methodically work through all the steps checking everything as you go and you will eventually find something configured incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this correct: `Data Source = MYPCNAME,1434\\SQLEXPRESS;`? Are you expecting AWS to be able to access your own PC?